# Rellenar con espacio en blanco pagina web

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estoy tratando de realizar mediante JQuery una función que me elimine el espacio en blanco que se me queda en las páginas cuyo contenido es muy pequeño. Adjunto una imagen para aclarar la situación:

[image: Situación]

La idea que me han comentado es mediante JQuery calcular el tamaño que ocupa la pagina y ese molesto espacio en blanco me lo rellene en el medio de la página. Y que el pie de pagina que tengo llegue hasta el final.

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?, estaría bien poder ver tu código.

Comment: ¿Poner un color/imagen de fondo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ponerle al bloque del texto una altura mínima, que cuando el texto sea largo ocupe todo lo que necesite y en caso de que el texto sea muy corto ocupe al menos x píxel.

```
.bloque_texto{
   height: auto;
   min-height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió tu ayuda ;D

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la técnica de "pié de página" pegajoso.

La idea es que el "pié de página" sea posicionado de forma absoluta, en un contenedor que tiene como mínimo la altura completa de la página.

La estructura es así:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

header {
    background-color: red;
}

#content {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <header id="header">El encabezado</header>

    <div id="content">
        <h2>Contenido</h2>
        <p>
            Contenido que no es tan largo
        </p>

    </div>

    <footer id="footer">
        El "footer" se posiciona de forma absoluta, y el padding inferior en #content evita que si la página es muy larga, este se superponga.
    </footer>
</div>
```

Importante tener en cuenta que debes conocer la altura del footer.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de poner unos pixels fijos lo suyo es ponerlo por porcentaje ya que no todas las pantallas son iguales y en una resolución te ira pero en otras no.
Lo suyo seria que en el contenedor donde tienes el texto le hicieras esto:

```
CSS:
.container{
    min-height:100vh;
}

HTML:
<div class="container">
   <p>Aqui va la seccion que quieras</p>
</div>
```

De esta manera el contenedor donde ira el texto siempre ara el 100% de alto como mínimo de la pantalla que se use. Ya que en los ordenadores tienen una altura mas pequeña que las pantallas de los móviles.

Answer (score -1):

Siguiendo la idea del uso del **Sticky Footer** o Pie Pegajoso como solución sugerida anteriormente puedes utilizar **Flexbox** y **Calc** de **CSS3** para conseguirlo independientemente del tamaño del contenido central y el dispositivo mediante el cual se esté visualizando.

Para que se aprecie el resultado he incluido un Encabezado y Pie de página con altura fija y la altura del Contenido es variable teniendo en cuenta las medidas de la pantalla mediante el uso de la función calc() de CSS3.

Utilizo Flexbox en el contenedor de las tres secciones y la propiedad flex-direction para colocar los objetos en columnas.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  width: 100vw;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

#header {
  background-color: #999;
  height: 50px
}

#content {
  background-color: #888;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: calc(100% - 0px - 100px);
}

#footer {
  background-color: #777;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id="header">header</section>
  <section id="content">content</section>
  <section id="footer">footer</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/301376)

Comment: La idea es que expliques **aquí** la solución.

Comment: Tenéis toda la razón ;)